# CSS: insert background image with a property of width: 100% and have text in the middle of the image

Tags: html, css, image, height, background-image

I have looked through stack and haven't found a solution

I am trying to insert a background image (1318 x 690) with the property

```
.bgImage {
 background-image: url('../img/background.jpg');
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
 }
```

first off, the full image is not showing up. its only about 30px tall and 100% width. and getting the text horizontally aligned is easy text-align:center and I think the vertical-align: middle.

Is there a way to display the image to it's fullest. What I am trying to do is make an image shape to the window it is being displayed in (mobile, desktop, and tablet). I think it is not showing because there is no content inside the element. Would it be better to use HTML's img?

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, I would take this approach:

```
.bgImage {
   background-image: url('../img/background.jpg') no-repeat center center;
   background-size: cover;
   text-align: center;
 }
```

And for the text (let's say it's an h1) I would do this (make sure the container has a position of relative, though):

```
h1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

And if your background image isn't spanning the height because its content isn't filling it, you can always use this quick jQuery trick:

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $win = $(window).height();
  $('.wrapper').height($win);
});
```

Edit: If you need it to be responsive, just in case, you can also bind it to resize:

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $(window).bind("load resize", function() {
    $win = $(window).height();
    $('.wrapper').height($win);
  });
});
```

This just sets the height of your main container (whether it be .container or .wrapper or whatever) to the full height of the browser window.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Set **[`background-size:cover;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size)** or **[`background-size:100% 100%;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size)**

```
.bgImage {
 background-image: url('../img/background.jpg');
 background-size:cover;
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
}
```

For more information and demo visit **[here](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/)**

Answer (score 0):

Use `background-size:100% 100%`

```
.bgImage {
     background-image: url('../img/background.jpg');
     width: 100%;
     text-align: center;
     background-size:100% 100%;
     }
```

Comment: I've tried to add that. But for some strange reason, nothing is showing up at all.